# Can Spider-Man climb ice walls?

Tags: spider-man, marvel

Can Spider-Man climb ice walls with his hands and/or his web?

Are there examples where Spider-Man encountered ice, or other evidence of his superpower under cold conditions?

Comment: Quick, someone warn Jon Snow! The Others are coming with their Ice Spider-men!

Comment: Can a regular spider climb ice walls? Because if THEY can, and HE does whatever a spider can...

Comment: @RyanPerry: But if a spider can't, it doesn't mean Spider-Man can't.

Comment: @Jeff That's right. I've never seen a spider work as a freelance photographer.

Comment: Listen bud, he's got radioactive blood...

Comment: @KSmarts That’s because when spiders do it, they call them _paparazzi_ instead.

Comment: More importantly, can [Iceman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iceman_(Marvel_Comics)) can climb [spider walls](https://terraria.gamepedia.com/Spider_Wall)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [Marvel Universe Wiki](http://marvel.wikia.com/Peter_Parker_(Earth-616)#Powers) describes the wall-clinging ability as a "ability to mentally control the flux of inter-atomic attraction (electrostatic force) between molecular boundary layers."

Basically, his stickiness is due to a telekinetic ability to increase attraction between surfaces on a molecular level (akin to increasing the static charge on a balloon). Theoretically, he'd be able to do this enough to stick to literally any surface, regardless of how slippery the surface is. I'd imagine it would only take an increased concentration on "being sticky."

I read somewhere once that due to the telekinetic behaviour of his abilities, he isn't allowed to play poker with the Avengers.

Comment: That point about poker is... strange. Telekinesis doesn't allow you to read people's thoughts, it lets you manipulate physical systems with your mind. The Spider Sense might be useful during a poker game, but that has nothing to do with telekinesis.

Comment: @NuclearWang Telekinetic powers like the ones described in the answer, which make things stick to your hands, would help a dishonest player hold on to certain cards.

Comment: @RyanVeeder True, but Spiderman would never actively cheat! Plus, it doesn't really help unless you practice the sleight-of-hand needed to hide the cheating, which most anyone can learn without superpowers. I'd be far more worried playing with the Flash or Superman.

Answer (score 8):

As seen in [The Amazing Spider-Man Volume 1, issue 92](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Amazing_Spider-Man_Vol_1_92), page 5, last panel...
[image: It's falling on your hindquarters that hurts]
...Spidey can't stick to ice.

Comment: As an actual instance of spidey encountering ice, this seems superior to the accepted answer.

Comment: I'd question whether this actually presents an argument against Spidey being able to stick to ice.  All this demonstrates is that when you suddenly ice over the spot Spidey is about to step, he can slip.  There's no indication he was using his wall clinging ability on the ground at the time.

Comment: @jeff he has superhuman reflexes and a spider sense on top of that... I'd say he slips.

Answer (score 2):

Ice is solid water.  It has a low coefficient of friction when a layer of water forms between it and whatever is rubbing on it - think ice skate.  Without the layer of water, it is just another solid.

Spider-man's climb is, in theory, about microscopic hairs that work like ice-climbers picks into all surfaces. The kind of friction normal hands have is about bulk-surface against bulk-surface. One of the consequences of the hair-bridge is that it is going to be a poor conductor of heat when contrasted against the bulk friction of a normal hand.  Heat transfer is about cross-sectional area and the hair-area is negligible compared to the surface area of the hand.

Bottom line: If he can climb smoothed concrete, then he can climb ice.  It is going to work better if it is not right at melting point or soppy-wet though.

Links to answers about how 'Spidey' climbs:

- [How does Spider-Man climb walls?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/55588/how-does-spider-man-climb-walls)
- https://www.dailymail.co.uk/sciencetech/article-2839488/Spiderman-style-gloves-let-climb-walls-GLASS.html

[image: Microscopic hais on hands]

In general they are muscle-control driven biological microstructures. The points above about applicability to concrete/solids, melting points, and heat transfer apply to the biological microstructures as long as they are not a biological analog of a [heat-pipe](https://www.1-act.com/resources/heat-pipe-calculator/).

Comment: Spidey doesn't always climb via 'hairs', some versions have other adhesive properties.

Comment: @Jeff yeah but that version was particularly lonely.

Answer (score 0):

NO

Spider-Man cannot climb ice walls because his grip hairs freeze off. Its like licking a lamp post in winter. He can't move his hands.

Featured in issue of "The Amazing Spider-Man" #92

Comment: Do you have any images from that issue?

Comment: I can't see anything in that issue that would support your statement. The closest he comes is that he slips on ice.